# Multi entity manager, wrong database selected

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

---

Hello,
i'm using multiple entity managers in Symfony 2, but during a form validation, the handleRequest method use the wrong one.

Here is my ORM configuration :

```
dbal:
        default_connection: customer_database
        connections:
            customer_database:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
            shared_database:
                driver:   %shared_database_driver%
                host:     %shared_database_host%
                port:     %shared_database_port%
                dbname:   %shared_database_name%
                user:     %shared_database_user%
                password: %shared_database_password%     
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager: customer_em
        entity_managers:
            shared_em:
                connection: shared_database
                mappings:
                    KnFEngineBundle:
                        type: "annotation"
                        dir: "Entity/Shared"
            customer_em:
                connection: customer_database
                mappings:
                    KnFEngineBundle:
                        type: "annotation"
                        dir: "Entity/Customer"
                    KnFModTextBundle: ~
                    KnFModMapBundle: ~
                    KnFModFormBundle: ~
```

And the function in my controller that validate the form :

```
public function addAction( $isLink )
{
    $kernel = $this->container->get( 'knf_engine.kernel' );
    $form = $this->createForm( new PageType( $isLink, $kernel->getAvailablePageOwner() ) );

    $request = $this->get( 'request' );
    if( $request->getMethod() == 'POST' )
    {
        $page = new Page( $isLink );
        $form->setData( $page );
        $form->handleRequest( $request ); //the function call that throw error
        if( $form->isValid() )
        {   
            $kernel->addPage( $page );
            return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl( 'knf_engine_admin_page' ) );
        }
    }

    $args = array(  'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'url' => $this->getURL(),
                    'isLink' => $isLink );

    if( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() )
    {
        return $this->render( 'KnFEngineBundle:admin:includes/pageadd_modal.html.twig', $args );
    }
    else
    {           
        return $this->render(   'KnFEngineBundle:admin:pageadd.html.twig', $args );
    }
}
```

And the error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.isLink AS isLink2, t0.externalLink AS externalLink3, t0.isPopup AS isPopup4, t0.address AS address5, t0.position AS position6, t0.title AS title7, t0.active AS active8, t0.owner_id AS owner_id9 FROM Page t0 WHERE t0.address = ?' with params ["dhfg"]:
    SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'kreanet_framework_global.page' doesn't exist
```

But the entity is "Page" is defined in the Entity/Customer folder, that is mapped to the customer entity manager (default em). As you can see, doctrine try to access the data in the other entity manager.

After investigation, i understood that doctrine bind the form with the database in the handleRequest() method (i used bind() before but is now deprecated).
I really don't know why doctrine is looking in that database.

Thanks for reading and sorry for my english, it's not my native language but i hope you can understand my problem.

Comment: [Using multiple MySQL entity managers for multiple bundles and databases](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/7cpx/using-multiple-mysql-entity-managers-for-multiple-bundles-and-databases)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. But in my case i was using

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"field1", "field2"})
```

So the problem was not entityManager but the UniqueEntity constrain the solution:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"field1", "field2"}, em="entityManagerName")
```